# getting 404 error for java restful webservices using jersy

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am new to Restful webservices and when i am trying to write a weebservice i am getting 404 error. Could you please let me know if i did something wrong.

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestFulWebService</display-name>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.core.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>restful.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Java class:

```
package restful.service;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/hello")
public class JersyService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getMsg() {

        String output = "Jersey say : ";

        return output;

    }
}
```

Jars:

i have included all the jars (i got issues in the beginning have resolved it)

```
The url i am using is
```

http://localhost:8080/RestFulWebService/rest/hello

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your `web.xml` file, it seems that your service has been deployed on

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Try this url instead

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/hello
```

#### OR

Edit your `web.xml` by changing your `servlet-mapping`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RestFulWebService/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### EDIT

Your `getMsg()` method is producing a `MediaType.TEXT_XML` and since your `output` is not in XML format, the service won't be able to represent the response as XML as requested.

**Solution 1**
Edit the annotation value by any text media type such as :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getMsg() {
    String output = "Jersey say : ";

    return output;
}
```

**Solution 2**
Change your `output` such as :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getMsg() {
    String output = "<something>Jersey say : </something>";

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Tried by changing the URL and by changing the web.xml also both of them have not worked

Comment: Ok, I see where the problem comes from. Your `get` method is producing `MediaType.TEXT_XML`. Since your string is not xml formated, the service does not understand how to produce a xml representation of your resource. Check the edited answer.